# Haskell not lazy evaluating interleaving

Tags: haskell

I am working through a problem (its from a UPenn class, but I am not taking it (just working through it to learn Haskell)), and the point is to construct a Stream (as defined below), that is defined by "ruler" (ruler !! n = the exponent of the highest power of 2 which will divide n). The issue is that I think that the definition for ruler below should lazily evaluate, but it seems to be evaluating strictly and running infinitely. If I cap it by adding a terminal case like "nthStream 10 = streamRepeat 10" it runs and generates output up to the point I want correctly.

```
data Stream a = Stream a (Stream a)

streamToList :: Stream a -> [a]
streamToList (Stream a rest) = [a] ++ streamToList rest

instance Show a => Show (Stream a) where
    show s = show $ take 100 $ streamToList s

streamRepeat :: a -> Stream a
streamRepeat a = Stream a (streamRepeat a)

interleaveStreams :: Stream a -> Stream a -> Stream a
interleaveStreams (Stream a arest) (Stream b brest) = (Stream a (Stream b (interleaveStreams arest brest)))

nthStream :: Integer -> Stream Integer

nthStream n = interleaveStreams (streamRepeat n) (nthStream (n+1))

ruler :: Stream Integer
ruler = nthStream 0
```

Can anyone explain why ruler (and nthStream) is not lazily evaluating?

Comment: Shouldn't there be a base case for `streamRepeat`?

Comment: @shree.pat18 `streamRepeat` should return an infinite stream, if I'm not mistaken, much like `repeat :: a -> [a]` in Prelude.

Comment: bheklir, you are correct. it should return an infinite stream. example: streamRepeat 3 = Stream 3 (Stream 3 (Stream 3....

Comment: @bheklilr Fair enough. But I'm unable to see where there's a base case to end recursion for any of the functions? Perhaps I'm just being very dense?

Comment: @shree.pat18 `take 10 $ streamToList ruler` should return, but it doesn't.

Comment: @bheklilr So basically the terminal case must be defined explicitly right?

Comment: @shree.pat18 I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "terminal case" or "defined explicitly".  What causes it to terminate is how much of the infinite data structure is requested, not any of the functions defined in the question.

Comment: @shree.pat18 that's kind of the point of the lazy evaluation. you are free to work with an infinitely recursive objects. Like for instance you can write z = map (\x -> x + 1) [0..].

Comment: OK, thanks both. I guess I was confused about lazy evaluation when I asked.

Comment: @shree.pat18 No problem! clearly I am confused about something as well because I can't get this to work

Comment: @shree.pat18 you were thinking about recursion, but this is [corecursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corecursion).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll try to nudge you in the right direction, or at least point out what's going wrong.  The function `nthStream` will never evaluate, not even its first element, because of how it's defined with `interleaveStreams`.  To give you an example, let's work out what it evaluates to for `nthStream 0` (for brevity and readability I've renamed `nthStream` to `nth`, `interleaveStream` to `interleave`, `streamRepeat` to `repeat`, and `Stream` to `Strm`):

```
nth 0 = interleave (repeat 0) (nth 1)
      = interleave (Strm 0 _0) (interleave (repeat 1) (nth 2))
      = interleave (Strm 0 _0) (interleave (Strm 1 _1) (nth 2))
      = interleave (Strm 0 _0) (interleave (Strm 1 _1) (interleave (repeat 2) (nth 3)))
      = interleave (Strm 0 _0) (interleave (Strm 1 _1) (interleave (Strm 2 _2) (nth 3)))
```

I've chosen to represent the tails of each stream returned from `repeat` as `_N` where `N` is the number being repeated.  These are currently thunks, since we haven't had to request their values yet.  Notice how what is building up is a chain of `interleave`s, rather than a chain of `Strm` constructors.  We get each one we're interested in, but they can never return from `interleave` until the second argument is evaluated.  Since the second argument is always getting reduced to a new call to `interleave`, it'll never reduce.

Here's a hint: how can you define `interleaveStreams` recursively so that it only depends on its first argument being constructed already?  i.e.

```
interleaveStreams (Stream a arest) streamB = Stream a (???)
```

Comment: would this work?

interleaveStreams (Stream a arest) streamB = Stream a (interleaveStreams streamB arest) ?

Comment: @BrettJurman I don't know, you tell me.  Does that make `nthStream` evaluate if you do `take 10 $ streamToList $ nthStream 0`?  Does `interleaveStream` still take two streams and interleave them together properly?

Comment: @BrettJurman Basically, what I'm saying is that you've found a possible solution, so test it!  Does it give you the response you expected?

Comment: It does seem to work. Thanks! Sorry I hadn't test it, I was trying to go to sleep, but I felt I should respond because you were being helpful

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is the line

```
interleaveStreams (Stream a arest) (Stream b brest) = (Stream a (Stream b (interleaveStreams arest brest)))
```

In order for that function to return even the beginning of a result, *both* of its arguments have to be evaluated, because you are pattern matching directly on their constructors. But you are using it in

```
nthStream n = interleaveStreams (streamRepeat n) (nthStream (n+1))
```

Which means that `nthStream n` cannot return *anything* until `nthStream (n+1)` has been evaluated, which gives you an infinite recursion.

To fix this, you can change the second pattern in the problematic line to be explicitly *lazy* with a `~`:

```
interleaveStreams (Stream a arest) ~(Stream b brest) = (Stream a (Stream b (interleaveStreams arest brest)))
```

Comment: I didn't even know about the "explicitly" lazy concept. Given that this works, it seems like I should be able to write it without it somehow? Is there an alternative that more or less does what I want? I may be confused, but thanks!

Comment: @BrettJurman There is certainly a way to do it without the irrefutable pattern, I was hoping you could figure it out from my answer ;).  Instead of pattern matching on the second argument, is there a way to define `interleaveStreams` where you don't need both heads of each stream immediately?  Check my answer for a slightly updated hint.

Comment: @bheklilr I responded to this in your answer thread. Thank you for the tips!